# Bug when uploading pictures with Arabic name characters?

Tags: images, uploads

Why when I upload a picture with its name with Arabic characters, like: الاتحاد.jpg to WordPress, the File name appears as: %d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%aa%d8%ad%d8%a7%d8%af ?

But in the old version of wordpress, its work good.

I try to download new wordpress file and its still same error.

Its error in wordpress core code.

Instead, its Title and URL are correct. Please, see this screen capture: http://prntscr.com/cjtxrf

Answer (score 0):

This is due to URL encoding `urlencode()` please read this http://php.net/urlencode

URLs and file names may contain unsafe characters so Wordpress encode them.